# How can I convert a .eml file to a .mbox file for Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, windows

How can I convert a **Windows Live Mail** eml file to **Apple Mail** mbox file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the PC with windows live mail.

1. Install thunderbird on the PC. This will allow you to import windows live mail, outlook express
   mails etc.
2. Create a gmail account, with IMAP enabled. Upload your imported email from thunderbird to gmail. This should be as simple as dragging the mail over.
3. Point your Mail.app at gmail and download your mail.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shell script and also a ruby script here - http://tinyapps.org/blog/misc/201110180700_eml2mbx.html

Ruby script did not work for me but shell script worked nicely. Both are free options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one](http://www.weirdkid.com/products/emailchemy/) solution I found... Here is [another](http://www.birdiesoftware.com/eml-to-mbox/), and [another](http://www.pcvare.com/convert-windows-mail-to-mac-mail.html). I thought there was a free solution, but I cannot find it.. Hope these help. I will keep looking..

Answer (score -1):

Klammer will open Outlook .msg files, standard .eml files, and also winmail.dat files on your iPad. We purchased the app and took it for a spin on our iPad, testing its ability to open both eml and Outlook msg files. 
It will be found at apple store.